# redux StateToProps acts strange. this.props is undefined but not always

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, undefined

I have a button that edits some things on the page, I want to change the text inside the button according to the role of the user.
the button has a onClick function, inside this function the "this.props.login.role" is defined and works as should. but when I put the "this.props.login.role" between the  tags it is undefined. cant understand why.

also everywhere else the redux is working properly so its not a problem in the rootReducer or the store.

Here's the button:

```
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
        if (
            this.props.login.role === "admin" ||
            this.props.login.role === "editor"
        ) {
            this.showDrawer();
        } else {
            toast.info("אין הרשאות", {
                position: "top-center",
                autoClose: 2500,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
            });
        }
    }}
    className="btn btn-outline-warning"
>
    {this.props.login.role === "noob" ? "1" : "2"}
</button>
```

Here's the redux:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { home: state.home, login: state.login };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        editSwitch: (SwData, newMac) =>
            dispatch(HomeActions.EditMacAdressOfSwitch(SwData, newMac)),
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditSwitch);
```

The strange part to me is if i remove the dynamic text from the buttom it works (still got this.props in the onClick and it is not undefined). see here what i mean :

```
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
        if (
            this.props.login.role === "admin" ||   //this works right! how it is not undefined here?
            this.props.login.role === "editor"
        ) {
            this.showDrawer();
        } else {
            toast.info("אין הרשאות", {
                position: "top-center",
                autoClose: 2500,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
            });
        }
    }}
    className="btn btn-outline-warning"
>
    static text // here's a static text
</button>
```

I guess i'm missing something with the "this" binding, but I can't get it. thanks' for your help (:

Comment: with only seeing the jsx return it is hard to see what values are accessible on `this`

Answer (score 1):

In your ***render*** method, if you deconstruct the prop as:  `const {role}=this.props.login` and use `role` instead of `this.props.login.role`
you can get the role, as follow:

```
...
 render() {
        const { role } = this.props.login
        return (
           
                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => {
                        if (
                            role === "admin" ||
                            role === "editor"
                        ) {
                            this.showDrawer();
                        } else {
                            toast.info("אין הרשאות", {
                                position: "top-center",
                                autoClose: 2500,
                                hideProgressBar: false,
                                closeOnClick: true,
                                pauseOnHover: true,
                                draggable: true,
                                progress: undefined,
                            });
                        }
                    }}
                    className="btn btn-outline-warning"
                >
                    {role === "noob" ? "1" : "2"}
                </button>
            
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found that the problem is the component renders before the data (all the login data) loads. and because of this the undefined happens.
now it works (I still don't like this solution but it works).

```
<button
      type="button"
      onClick={this.showDrawer}
      className="btn btn-outline-warning"
    >
      {this.props.login === undefined
        ? "static"
        : this.props.login.role === "noob"
        ? "1"
        : "1"}
    </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), so you should use **this.props?.login?.role**, hope it solve your problem

Comment: This is just a precaution to prevent undefined. It doesn't resolve the original issue.